# Synchronous call to Durable Orchestrator Function that waits for activity completion (Python Azure Functions)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, synchronous, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to build a durable function in which the orchestrator waits for activity completion and then returns the results af the activities. I am able to get the 'standard' asynchronous Function Chaining Python example from the [Azure Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence?tabs=python) to work.

Now I would like to make the call to the orchestrator client function synchronous, to wait for completion of the activity functions and return the outputs of the activity functions directly, instead of using the `create_check_status_response()` method and return `statusQueryGetUri` endpoint.

I have seen that there exists a `waitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponse()` method ([Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions-durable/azure.durable_functions.models.durableorchestrationclient?view=azure-python#azure-durable-functions-models-durableorchestrationclient-wait-for-completion-or-create-check-status-response)), which is also used in this [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=python#wait-for-orchestration-completion). This should be exactly what I am looking for, but I cannot get it to work.

My current set-up is the following: the `E1_HelloSequence` orchestrator and `E1_SayHello` activity functions with corresponding `function.json` files exactly the same as in the [first link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence?tabs=python) and orchestrator client is an exact copy as in the [Durable Functions instance management docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=python#wait-for-orchestration-completion):

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

timeout = "timeout"
retry_interval = "retryInterval"

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)

    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params['functionName'], None, req.get_body())
    logging.log(f"Started orchestration with ID = '${instance_id}'.")

    timeout_in_milliseconds = get_time_in_seconds(req, timeout)
    timeout_in_milliseconds = timeout_in_milliseconds if timeout_in_milliseconds != None else 30000
    retry_interval_in_milliseconds = get_time_in_seconds(req, retry_interval)
    retry_interval_in_milliseconds = retry_interval_in_milliseconds if retry_interval_in_milliseconds != None else 1000

    return client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(
        req,
        instance_id,
        timeout_in_milliseconds,
        retry_interval_in_milliseconds
    )

def get_time_in_seconds(req: func.HttpRequest, query_parameter_name: str):
    query_value = req.params.get(query_parameter_name)
    return query_value if query_value != None else 1000
```

This gives the following error:

```
Exception: TypeError: class <class 'bytes'> does not expose a `to_json` function"
```

Do I maybe need to change the `http` output binding type to something else in the `function.json`, in order to get this to work?

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "route": "orchestrators/{functionName}",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "type": "durableClient",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Can someone point out what I need to change in order to get this to work like expected? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're passing a `bytes` object that you get from `req.get_body()`:

```py
    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params['functionName'], None, req.get_body())
```

Without knowing the function you're choosing to call, it seems likely that this function is expecting an `HttpRequest` object rather than this `bytes` representation of the request body (since it's attempting to call a `to_json()` method on it). Changing `req.get_body()` to just `req` should solve this.

I also noted that you're missing an `await` before your call to `client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response`.

Comment: Adding the await() before the call to client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response() was indeed the solution, now my function returns the outputs to the caller directly (along with your other suggested change)

Comment: Additional question: how can I trow a custom HTTP error code to the client when an Activity Function fails? Now it will return a 500: Internal Server error, but I would like to make this adjustable depending on the error (e.g. 400 or 403)

Comment: The question is still actual for me. Is it possible to adjust the status code in node.js for waitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponse response?